# How to change build after successfully submitting your app to the app store?

Tags: xcode

we submitted our app to the app store with a current version of 1.0 and a build number of 1.3.2.
After successfully submitting our app it was now ready for sale. The problem now is we made a few changes and wish to upload a new build 1.3.3 but I am getting this error.

"This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [1.0] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [1.0]"

[image]

I understand that it suggested to change version to a higher version to fix this matter. But if we change this version it will cause the app to be reviewed once again wouldn't it?

Comment: chnage in info.plist file Bundle versions string, short String and use 2.0 version and Build 2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once an app is Ready For Sale, you have to submit a new version (not build) and yes, it will be reviewed.

Comment: But once I submit a new version, do I have to keep creating a new version everytime I make a few changes?

Comment: I understand now. So after you submitted your app in the app store, per app release you need to change the version to a higher version... unlike in the development stage where you only need to change the build. Is this correct sir?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid so.